# ASP.NET Core redirect to login page without return url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I have a Razor Page (.NET 6) project with ASP.NET Core Identity, on startup I set the access path and access denied path like this:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = Constants.Cookies.Authentication;
    options.LoginPath = Constants.Pages.Login; // /Account/Login
    options.AccessDeniedPath = Constants.Pages.Login; 
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
 });
```

my OnGet method on the login page accepts the return URL, like so:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string returnUrl)
{
     // Some action when returnUrl is from external client
}
```

the problem is that when a user is on the profile page:

```
// Profile page
[Authorize]
public class HomeModel : PageModel
{
     //....
}
```

and the cookie has expired, when the page is refreshed, the user is correctly redirected to the login page to re-login, but is populated the return url with the profile page value:

```
https://localhost:5002/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FProfile%2FHome%3Fculture%3Den
```

instead it should be null or empty.
How come this happens, is there a way to do the redirect without this parameter in the query string or should I then check in the get of the login that it is a local url to avoid some steps that I perform?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> is there a way to do the redirect without this parameter in the query
> string

Do you mean remove `?ReturnUrl=%2FProfile%2FHome%3Fculture%3Den` ?

If so, I suggest you create a custom authentication cookie:

```
public class CookieAuthEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    public override Task RedirectToLogin(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.RedirectUri = "/Account/Login";
        return base.RedirectToLogin(context);
    }

    public override Task RedirectToLogout(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.RedirectUri = "/Account/CustomLogout";
        return base.RedirectToLogout(context);
    }

    public override Task RedirectToAccessDenied(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.RedirectUri = "/Account/CustomAccessDenied";
        return base.RedirectToAccessDenied(context);
    }

    public override Task RedirectToReturnUrl(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.RedirectUri = "/CustomReturnUrl";
        return base.RedirectToReturnUrl(context);
    }
}
```

In programs, register authentication cookie

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<CookieAuthEvents>();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(ops =>
{
   //do your stuff...
    ops.EventsType = typeof(CookieAuthEvents);//add this line
   
});
```

result:

[image]

Comment: If I set the custom events I noticed that I no longer have these logs:
[17:37:14 INF] Identity.Application was not authenticated. Error message: no principal. <s1: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler>
[17:37:14 INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement - Requires an authenticated user. <s1: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService>
it is as if the handler is being bypassed
and that's not what I want.

Comment: Have you try string.Empty?

Comment: which point should I try string.Empty?

Comment: Can you share the code about your OnGet action?

Comment: There are simple ifs if the returnUrl is empty or not.